# Delete/Erase a particular url from Android web view history?

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to erase a specific url from the android's webview history? I Google a lot but was not able to find any sol, even i checked the api's documentation and i think there is no direct way to do the same.
have a look at below code:

```
// getting the whole list of web view's history....
WebBackForwardList list = wv.copyBackForwardList();
// getting previuous item/link 
String lastUrl = list.getItemAtIndex(list.getCurrentIndex()-1).getUrl();
```

From 2nd line of code it is clear that it is possible to play around with history, so i think there must be some way or trick to delete a particular link from web view history.
Does it makes any sense to you guys?

Any code snippet or any link will highly be appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, not sure if you actually can play around with the back forward list. I would assume it's a copy - at least that's what the name suggest.

However, you can manipulate the back stepping to some degree. In my case I exit the application already when user tries to step back from second page towards first page.

```
  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if ((action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && myWebView.canGoBack() ) {
                WebBackForwardList list = myWebView.copyBackForwardList();
                String lastUrl = list.getItemAtIndex(list.getCurrentIndex()-1).getUrl().toString();

                // Exit if index == 1, i.e. currently on 2nd page
                if (list.getCurrentIndex() == 1) {
                    finish();
                } else ...
```

You could step over also other other pages by combining stuff from above and overloading url loading:

```
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question and answer both helped us to find the following solution for our problem.

We wanted to jump back to particular url (partialUrl), which could be anywhere in WebBackForwardList. So we are using following code to goBackOrForward, based on the partial Url passed in method by theValueString parameter. ( We wanted to call the method from any other thread so using runOnUiThread )

```
if (!theValueString.isEmpty()) {
    final String partialUrl = theValueString;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // getting the whole list of web view's history....
            WebBackForwardList list = myWebview.copyBackForwardList();
            int index = list.getCurrentIndex();
            for (int i = list.getSize() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                String historyurl = list.getItemAtIndex(i).getUrl();
                if (historyurl.contains(partialUrl)) {
                    myWebview.goBackOrForward(i - index);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```